# Partially blocked out of my system (ports 21, 22 and maybe some others are inaccessible)

Tags: ssh, firewall

I have a remote Ubuntu system to which I login from my local one. Yesterday I mistakenly installed *denyhosts* just to do a test, on this remote machine, but the machine already had *CSF-LFD* installed and it seems there became some kind of conflict between them as since then I can't SSH or FTP into it **from my permanent ip**, although I can SSH or FTP it from other IPs just fine.

What I can do from my permanent IP is surfing in the websites based on this machine's *Apache* server and even access their DBs via *PHPmyadmin* or logging into their CMSs from a relevant URL, hence I say I'm **partially blocked**.

### To solve it, I tried from the hosting platform console:

```
(
sudo apt-get purge denyhosts
sudo apt-get purge fail2ban
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo sh /etc/csf/uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server -y
sudo apt-get install --reinstall iptables -y
sudo iptables -F.
sudo reboot
)
```

Still, after executing this code block, my ip is partially blocked and can't SSH or FTP into the system - When I SSH tunnel from my local desktop with WSL Ubuntu: `Connection closed by remote host`.

### Further details:

- I didn't replace either ftp or SSH ports from 21 or 22 to something else.
- I didn't manually block my IP on any port (but it seems it is blocked anyway).
- `/var/log/auth.log` doesn't contain any serious errors besides "connection refused".

`ps ax | grep ssh`:

```
1379 ? Ss 0:01 /user/sbin/sshd -D
2362 pts/0 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

`netstat -plnt`:

[image]

`iptables -nvL`:

[image]

### My question:

What's left to cause this after the aforementioned actions and given the charts seem fine?

Comment: Can you post the output of "ps ax | grep ssh" and "netstat -plnt", ran locally from your remote system through your hosting providers control panel?

Comment: Posted outputs above (in the second I putted an image as I can't copy to clipboard from hosting platform console).

Comment: Thanks. Everything looks okay there; `ps ax` shows that sshd (the SSH daemon) is running and `netstat -plnt` shows that it is listening and waiting for connections. Can you also run "iptables -nvL" and screenshot the output into your post as well?

Comment: I just updated.

Comment: Can you SSH from the server, onto itself? So `ssh root@localhost` for example.

Comment: It seems I can: I just did that and was then notified `Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.` BTW, I tried to do the same on my local machine and again got `Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.` but right afterwards: `Write failed: Connection reset by peer`.

Comment: Anyway, now when I do ssh `root@localhost` in my remote machine It seems I stay on the same place without an error so I guess it works.

Comment: This suggests to me that sshd is running and accepting connections, so it's setup and configured correctly, but for some reason you are being blocked from accessing it from your local computers.

Do your laptop and computer have different external IP addresses? Do they share a router or internet connection, or are they both totally independent from one another in terms of network connectivity?

Comment: You are right. They had the same IP. I was wrong. While I was away in Germany, my brother setted up a Wifi on my IP even though I told him not to set one up. I tried to login from the laptop with the same IP and hence the disconnect. Anyway, that shows that my problem is due to a blockage of my own IP... The one I usually use from my desktop... This is a milestone I would say...

Comment: WOW, even after `apt-get install --reinstall iptables && reboot`, I can't login from my IP...

Comment: I think you still have a utility running which is denying SSH access to your IP address. fail2ban does this, but as you've said you have removed it - so I don't know what it could be. Are you able to reinstall the OS through your hosting control panel? This might be the easiest and quickest solution, but you will loose all your data..

What is the output of `service fail2ban status`?

Comment: `fail2ban.service` and `Loaded: Not found (no such file or directory)` and `Active: inactive (dead)`.

Comment: It's problematic for me to install it anew but I start to consider it. I will try to fully remove IPtables and purely install them then.

Comment: Even after I fully removed `iptables` I still can't login with my ip (maybe only the interface was removed), but still it's wired.

Comment: iptables is just a firewall; we confirmed that your iptables rules aren't at fault by running `iptables -nvL` early on (there are no DENY rules - this isn't secure but it wouldn't cause the problem you are describing). I really think there is something else which is causing this, but I really don't know what :(

Comment: Published an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to blockage of my permanent ip address in the file `/etc/hosts.deny`. To solve it I ssh'd from my laptop (because I can't copy and paste from clipboard in my hosting platform's console and that's super uncomfortable and illogistical).

Removing the ip from the file is problematic because it could then comeback due to misconfigurations or bugs so to solve it just add your permanent id to `/etc/hosts.allow` (which is your "always allowed" list). I did so directly from console this way (but ofcourse you can use a text editor or an ftp client like Filezilla):

```
bash -c "echo 'sshd: IP_ADDRESS' >> /etc/hosts.allow"
```

This solution deals with ip evaluation: Basically when you try to login into a remote environment, first the list of allowed ip's is checked, if your ip is in the **allowed list**, you get in, if it isn't, the evaluation continues to the **denied list**, and if your ip is there - You don't get in. To learn more on this, [please see this Q&A session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359292/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-file-etc-hosts-deny/359295#359295)

After doing so, I could ssh from my permanent ip just fine. I than made sure to install *CSF-LFD* again, and to update everything:

```
  apt-get install iptables -y
  apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server -y
  cd /usr/src && rm -fv csf.tgz
  wget https://download.configserver.com/csf.tgz && tar -xzf csf.tgz
  cd csf && sh install.sh
  sed -i 's/TESTING = "1"/TESTING = "0"/g' /etc/csf/csf.conf
  csf -r && perl /usr/local/csf/bin/csftest.pl
  apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

### Note:

If you prefer making changes from your laptop instead of your hosting platform console, but can't login from the laptop, make sure that your laptop's ip is different from your permanent ip.

I was sure it's different for a few hours and didn't understand why I can't login from the laptop as well but what I didn't know is that While I was away in Germany, my brother setted up a Wifi on my ip (even though I asked him not to do so). This mislead me to think that any ip is partially blocked, but I found that out and chose our other ip network and could ssh regularly to remove blockage of the permanent ip comfortably.

Comment: A related case, that could shed some light on the behavior I experienced: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225300/denyhosts-keeps-adding-back-my-ip